# How can we play .mov file in fancybox, using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, mov, .mov

My goal was to play a mov-file that's already uploaded on my server and it'd be nice to have it pop up inframe using fancybox and jquery. However I have attempted with no luck substituting .mov to swf-type in these codes:

```
<a class="various" href="Poem.MOV">Play movie</a>
```

with this Jquery from the fancybox website's suggestion-list:

```
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".various").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This only sent me to a different webpage playing that mov-file. A different and closest code that ever worked by popping the video up in a fancybox inframe successfully BUT does not play or even show up at all. It only showed up in white frame without playing the film:

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" data-type="swf" href="Poem.MOV" title="Poem">Play Movie</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".fancybox").on("click", function(){
        $.fancybox({
          href: this.href,
          type: $(this).data("type")
        }); // fancybox
        return false   
    }); // on
}); // ready
</script>
```

I wonder if this is feasible to play .mov on our own server using fancybox without using third-party server such as YouTube or Vimeo. Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/67

Comment: That certainly did the trick! I almost wrote that it didnt work but fixing it to lowercases of the file extension (.mov) also made a difference. egads. THANK YOU @JFK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JWplayer player` with `fancybox` to play the `.mov` or other video formats.
below is the code to integrate `jWplayer with fancybox`:

```
$(".various").fancybox({
        fitToView: true,
        content: '<div id="myJWPlayer">Loading the player ...</div>',
        scrolling: 'no',
        afterShow: function () {
          var video_href= j(this.element).data('url');
          $('#myJWPlayer').css({height:'400px',width:'500px'});
          setTimeout(function(){
            jwplayer('myJWPlayer').setup({
                'file' : video_href,
                "autostart" : "true",
                "controlbar" : "bottom",
                "flashplayer" : "url-to-/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                "volume" : "70",
                "width" : 500,
                "height" : 400,
                "mute" : "false",
                "stretching" : "fill"
            });
            updateViewTime(vid);
          },100);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where the HTML5 video player worked, but loading the same .mov into fancybox did not play. My solution was to either add the url of the video directly to the video tag, or to set the "type" attribute of the source tags as empty in the afterLoad() callback.

```
const attachment_movie = [ 'mp4', 'mov' ];

$.fancybox.open(gallery, {
    buttons: [
      'download',
      'zoom',
      'slideShow',
      'thumbs',
      'close'
    ],
    thumbs: { 'autoStart': true },
    afterLoad : function() {
        var href = this.src;
        var ext = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        
        if ( $.inArray(ext, attachment_movie) > -1 )
          $('.fancybox-video').prop('src', href);
        // or
        if ( $.inArray(ext, attachment_movie) > -1 )
          $('.fancybox-video source').prop('type', '');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to workaround the problem by replacing template for `<video>` tag. I added `src="{{src}}"` to the video tag. You can also pass that as a part of options.

```
$.fancybox.defaults.video = {
  ...$.fancybox.defaults.video,
  tpl: `
  <video class="fancybox-video" poster="{{poster}}" src="{{src}}">
    <source src="{{src}}" type="{{format}}" />Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos, 
    <a href="{{src}}">download</a> and watch with your favorite video player!
  </video>`
};
```